# Prevent endline after printing system time

Tags: c++, systemtime

I have a a simple question, if I want to print a value on the same line as the output of my system time, is this possible?

```
char *date;
time_t timer;
timer=time(NULL);
date = asctime(localtime(&timer));
//printf("Current Date: %s", date);


  std::cout << date << ", " << randomNumber  << std::endl;

  if (file.is_open())
  {
    file << date;
    file << ", ";
    file << randomNumber;
    file << "\n";
  }
```

What I was hoping would happen is that I would get this as an output:

```
Wed Jan 16 16:18:56 2013, randomNumber
```

But what I do end up getting in my file is :

```
Wed Jan 16 16:18:56 2013
, randomNumber
```

Also, I just did a simple std::cout, and I notice the same result. It seems that the system forces an end line at the end of the output, is there anyway, I can supress this?

Comment: You could just use the more general [`strftime`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strftime) with format string `"℅c"`...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can just replace the '\n' character in the date string (if null terminated it should be at strlen(date) - 1) with '\0' and it should print on the same line.

```
date[strlen(date) - 1] = '\0';
```

EDIT: As pointed out by Joachim `strlen` returns length without NULL terminator not raw allocation length so it should be -1 not -2.

Comment: That did work for me Jesus. I had modified it to -1, else it was eating the *3* of 2013. Thanks a lot, I need to wait for the timer to run down before I can accept your answer ..

Comment: Another quick question Jesus, how can I access merely the milli-second component of the time?

Comment: @c0d3rz You should use gettimeofday for that It gives you a struct timeval which has microseconds.

Answer (score 3):

The newline character is the last character in the string returned from `asctime`. The simplest way to remove it is to replace it with the string terminator character `'\0'`.

A note about Windows: Windows have *two* characters for newline, carriage-return `'\r'` and the regular newline `'\n'`. So on Windows you have to terminate at the *second* last character. If you want your code to be portable across Windows and non-Windows platforms you have to add checks for that.

Comment: 2nd to last character, last character should be \0 already :P

Comment: @JesusRamos Yes, but it's not counted when doing e.g. `strlen`.

Comment: You are correct, forgot about that. I thought of raw allocation length :P

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use strings you have better alternatives.

This worked for me:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<chrono>
#include<ctime>

using namespace std;

string getDate()
{
    chrono::system_clock::time_point tp = chrono::system_clock::now();
    time_t t = chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(tp);
    const char * tc = ctime(&t);
    string str = string {tc};
    str.pop_back();
    return str;
}

int main(){
    cout << getDate() << endl << hi;
}
```

Output:

```
Mon Dec  7 17:40:01 2015
hi
```

Answer (score -1):

this will work:

```
date = date.substr(0, date.size()-1);
```

Comment: Where in the code is that supposed to go?  Is it supposed to replace the existing `date =` assignment, go after it, or something else?

Comment: why down vote !! according to the questions we need to cut the "\n", which is the reason the automatic newline is occurring. we need to store the date as new srting.

Comment: you didn't read the question. yes, this code is suppose to replace the date with out the new line character. if you don't want so store it into another string.

Comment: Instead you could write date.pop_back() O(1) solution.